Does copying or moving folder/files retain the permissions?
What is the expected permissions behaviour when file/folder is copied or moved?
Does permissions get transferred along with the file/folder?
Does it matter if the folder has inheritence broken or not?

By default, when you copy a folder, it does not retain the custom permissions set on the original folder. Instead, it inherits the permissions from the destination library or folder.

What if you move? Or what if the destination or source folder has inheritence broken?

I have tested that the permissions of a file or folder remain the same as the permissions of the destination folder, whether it is moved or relocated. Even if the destination or original folder breaks the permission inheritance.
In short, the permissions of a file or folder remain the same as the destination folder's permissions (even if it is broken and has customized permissions).

No - my testing shows that if folder permission is broken, and this folder is moved to another folder (irrespective of whether or not destination folder has inheritence) this folder will stick to its unique permissions.
